# Bootstrap Form- unable to get full width on input & button when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Question background:**

I have a product details page that allows users to add a quantity of the item to their cart using a button. This is in a `inline-form` to allow the input and button to be placed next to each other, as shown:

[image]

**The issue:**

When the website has collapsed to be viewed on a small screen device I can't get the input and button to span the full width of the container. The following image shows how the site looks collapsed, **note** **the black arrows are pointing to the red lines I want the input and button to span to**:

[image]

**The HTML:**

```
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="testDesc">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="productQty" type="text" value="1" name="demo1" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="myLink">Add To Cart</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have width of those element `100%` you have to remove `<div class="input-group">` and add class `btn-block` to your button

```
  <form class="form-inline">
     <div class="form-group">
        <input id="productQty" type="text" value="1" name="demo1" class="form-control">            
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="myLink">Add To Cart</button>
  </form>
```